# How to cut the string from bash shell

Tags: bash

From linux Bash can you help me on how to show only the

```
Monitoringmetric=1.5Count
```

instead of

```
Monitoringmetric=1.5Count;1;2
```

Comment: `echo "Monitoringmetric=1.5Count;1;2" | cut -f1 -d";"`

Comment: You can use bash for this: `s='Monitoringmetric=1.5Count;1;2'; echo "${s%%;*}"`

Comment: Thanks Jean and anubhva, both suggestions works like  charm

can I ask one more on how can I only cut and show only = 1.5

Comment: Please don't turn the comment section into a Q-and-A session. If you have an answer, post it as an answer. @AppsTester If you have a follow-up question, post a new question.

Comment: FInally showed it but seems to be a long command, please advise if there is a way I can shorten this



$ echo "Monitoringmetric=1.5Count;1;2" | cut -f2 |sed -e 's/Monitoringmetric=//g' | cut -f1 -d ";" | sed -e 's/Count//g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be interested only capturing the number after the **Monitoringmetric=**, you can do:

```
echo "Monitoringmetric=1.5Count;1;2" | sed -n -e 's/^Monitoringmetric=\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

FInally showed it but seems to be a long command, please advise if there is a way I can shorten this

$ echo "Monitoringmetric=1.5Count;1;2" | cut -f2 |sed -e 's/Monitoringmetric=//g' | cut -f1 -d ";" | sed -e 's/Count//g'

Comment: Why are you doing the **cut -f2** that doesn't seem to accomplish anything? What are you trying to extrace from the input? Just **1.5** ?

Answer (score 0):

If your string is in a variable, you could also use ${a%%;*}, for example:

```
a="Monitoringmetric=1.5Count;1;2"
echo ${a%%;*}
```